# MVC basic application not working

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have created a fiddle online. If i enter 'Manoj' as username & 'kumar' as password and clicking on Login button, then i should get an alert message as 'Manoj kumar'. But this is not happening. I am sending username & password to controller action method, but they are not getting received in controller. Please tell what am i doing mistake.

```
            $('.submit').click(function(){
                if($('form').valid()) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '@Url.RouteUrl(new{ action="GetUserInfo", controller="Home"})',
                        data: JSON.stringify({userName: $("#txtUserName").val(), password: $("#txtPassword").val()}),
                            type: 'POST',
                            dataType: 'json',
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            success: function(resp) {
                            if(resp != null){

                                if(resp.IsValidUser == true){
                                    alert(resp.FullName);
                                }   
                                else{
                                    alert("Invalid Username or Password");
                                }

                            }

                        },

[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetUserInfo(string userName,string password)
    {

        ActionResult result = null;
        bool isValidUser = false;
        string fullName = string.Empty;
        if(userName == "Manoj" && password == "kumar")
        {
            isValidUser = true;
            fullName = userName +' ' + password;
        }
        else    {
            fullName = userName + ' '+password;
        }

        var resultObj = new {IsValidUser = isValidUser , FullName = fullName};

        result = Json(resultObj);

        return result;
    }
```

Please check the below link.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/KrWqwE

Comment: Code belongs here not in a fiddle. Use a code tag and look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Your code could be simplified with;

```
$.post('@Url.Action("Action", "Controler")',dataToPost).done(function(){
  //success
}).fail(function(){
  //fail
});
```

Get rid of the `application/json` part. And instead of click event you could use onsubmit event.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have Jquery Validate on your reference scripts since form.valid() will on it:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
```

Or check here for CDN: [JQuery Validate](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery-validate)

It is returning false that's why it doesn't proceed to your controller.

**Update**:

Make sure you put the code inside document ready and properly format the closure or ending brackets of your ajax function:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(fncInitialize);

    function fncInitialize() {
        $('#frmSubmit').click(function() {               
            if ($('form').valid()) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.RouteUrl(new{ action="GetUserInfo", controller="Home"})',
                    data: JSON.stringify({ userName: $("#txtUserName").val(), password: $("#txtPassword").val() }),
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function(resp) {
                        if (resp != null) {

                            if (resp.IsValidUser == true) {
                                alert(resp.FullName);
                            } else {
                                alert("Invalid Username or Password");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

</script>
```

This is the code for my input type submit:

```
<input type="submit" value="Create" id="frmSubmit" />
```

Comment: yes, it is available and form.valid() is returning true

Comment: I've tried your code, and its working fine. Have you put this in your document.ready? And have you formatted your function correctly? Kindly see my updated answer.